# How to handle FileNotFoundException in Java class extending AbstractMessageTransformer in Mule?

Tags: java, exception, mule, filenotfoundexception, mule-studio

I am using a custom transformer in mule and for that I am writing custom java code which extends  AbstractMessageTransformer.

I am facing a issue since in the custom java class since I need to handle FileNotFoundException
and it says   FileNotFoundException  is not compatible with AbstractMessageTransformer.

Is there any way I can handle  FileNotFoundException   in custom java class that extends AbstractMessageTransformer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MessageAttachmentTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer
{private List<String> filename; // file to attach
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
        if (filename.isEmpty() || filename==null || filename.size()==0) **//filename is a list contains list of file path as mule attachment**
        {**//If file for attachment is not there**
            **//Here I want to place FileNotFoundException**
            return message;} else
        { // do other thing} return message;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to re-throw the **FileNotFoundException** within a class extending an **AbstractMessageTransformer**, then you should probably wrap that exception into a **TransformerException**, the one thrown by the **doTransform** method

Your method will look like this

```
    try{
        //Your custom transformation
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Message msg = CoreMessages.transformFailedBeforeFilter();
        throw new TransformerException(msg,this, e);
    }
```

Comment: Could you Please Explain the way to wrap that exception into a TransformerException

Comment: Thanks ... I tried with **doTransform** and FileNotFoundException but didn't end up well

Comment: What problem are you experiencing with this approach?

Comment: public class MessageAttachmentTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer 
{ 
private List<String> filename; // file to attach 
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) 
throws TransformerException { 
if (filename.isEmpty() || filename==null || filename.size()==0)     //filename is a list contains list of file path as mule attachment {//If file for attachment is not there 
 **//Here I want to place  FileNotFoundException **
 return message; 
} 
else { // do other thing} 
return message; 
} 
} 
}

Comment: You should first check if the filename is null, otherwise filename.isEmpty() will most probably cause a NPE